# How to fill in float and integer in EditText in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I'm trying to fill in a integer and a float in a EditText field in my app. But my app keeps crashing.

This is how my XMl looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/int_LA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="LA"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/int_LB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:hint="LB"
        android:layout_below="@id/int_LA"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my JAVA code

```
package com.example.plaatuitslagberekenen;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.text.InputType.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView result;
    EditText int_LA, int_LB, int_LC, int_t, int_Ri_x, int_Ri_y;

    double result_num;
    double int_LA_num, int_LB_num, int_LC_num, int_t_num, int_Ri_x_num, int_Ri_y_num;
    double k_factor;
    double BA_1;
    double BA_2;
    double OneThirdth = 0.333333333;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        int_LA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.int_LA);

        int_LA.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        int_LB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.int_LB);
        int_LC = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.int_LC);
        int_t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.int_t);
        int_Ri_x = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.int_Ri_x);
        int_Ri_y = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.int_Ri_y);


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    //BA_1 = (double) (Math.PI / 180) * int_Ri_x_num * (double) (int_t_num + 0.33 * int_t_num );
                    int_LA_num = Integer.parseInt(int_LA.getText().toString());
                    int_LB_num = Integer.parseInt(int_LB.getText().toString());
                    int_LC_num = Integer.parseInt(int_LC.getText().toString());
                    int_t_num = Integer.parseInt(int_t.getText().toString());
                    int_Ri_x_num = Integer.parseInt(int_Ri_x.getText().toString());
                    int_Ri_y_num = Integer.parseInt(int_Ri_y.getText().toString());
                    //result_num = (int_t_num) + int_LC_num + int_LA_num + int_LB_num + int_Ri_x_num + int_Ri_y_num + k_factor;
                    result_num = ((int_LA_num - int_t_num) + (int_LB_num - (int_t_num * 2)) + (int_LC_num - int_t_num) + ((OneThirdth * int_t_num) / 90) * (int_Ri_x_num) + ((OneThirdth * int_t_num) / 90) * (int_Ri_y_num));
                    System.out.println(((OneThirdth * int_t_num) / 90) * (int_Ri_x_num));

                    result.setText(String.format("%.1f", result_num));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to have for LA_num sometimes a float and sometimes a integer. How can i convert this in this code.

EDIT:

```
result_num = ((int_LA_num - int_LB_num)
```

EDIT_2:

Crashlog after adding "int_LA.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);":

```
2020-04-21 19:47:47.163 12202-12202/com.example.plaatuitslagberekenen D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-04-21 19:47:47.164 12202-12202/com.example.plaatuitslagberekenen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.plaatuitslagberekenen, PID: 12202
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100.0"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.example.plaatuitslagberekenen.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2020-04-21 19:47:47.186 12202-12202/com.example.plaatuitslagberekenen I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12202 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What exception you are getting?
please attach the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take all the inputs as double:-

```
   double result_num;
    double int_LA_num, int_LB_num, int_LC_num, int_t_num, int_Ri_x_num, int_Ri_y_num;
    double k_factor;
    double BA_1;
    double BA_2;
    double OneThirdth = 0.333333333;

    int_LA_num = Double.parseDouble(int_LA.getText().toString());
    int_LB_num = Double.parseDouble(int_LB.getText().toString());
    int_LC_num = Double.parseDouble(int_LC.getText().toString());
    int_t_num = Double.parseDouble(int_t.getText().toString());
    int_Ri_x_num = Double.parseDouble(int_Ri_x.getText().toString());
    int_Ri_y_num = Double.parseDouble(int_Ri_y.getText().toString());
    //result_num = (int_t_num) + int_LC_num + int_LA_num + int_LB_num + 
    int_Ri_x_num + int_Ri_y_num + k_factor;
    result_num = ((int_LA_num - int_t_num) + (int_LB_num - (int_t_num * 2)) + 
    (int_LC_num - int_t_num) + ((OneThirdth * int_t_num) / 90) * 
    (int_Ri_x_num) + ((OneThirdth * int_t_num) / 90) * (int_Ri_y_num));
```

Comment: If i do this, my program says that i can use that in my sum, check the EDIT i made in my main post

Comment: I saw your edits editing my answer according to your changes.
You can take all the inputs as double. An integer is automatically casted in double by the JVM so take all of them in double then it won't matter if it's a double or integer you will get the result as a double.

Comment: Wauw!! It's working. That part is the most satisfying part of programming. Thank you a lot:)))))))))))) You made my day actually great :)

Answer (score 0):

you can change your EditText input type on runtime or on your specific condition.

```
int_LA.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

you can do parsing of your Edit Text data just before your computation.
Please share your crash logs to identify the reason of the crash.

Comment: Where can i put this?

Comment: "I want to have for LA_num sometimes a Float and sometimes an integer. How can I convert this in this code."

according to your logic when to you to accept as a Float.